# Delete specific line from .txt file (C++)

Tags: c++, delete-file

I am trying to scan through the content of a .txt file in order to compare it with a user's int input and once found the matching value, line where it is written to be removed.
The file DOES NOT have only numerical values. 
Ex of what the file contains: 
" hello world 505 " 
" hello world 506 " etc.

So far my code is able to make the comparison(the lines do not have the same length) but I do not know how to move the file pointer to the line where said value is found.Any help?

```
void comparisoniD2 (int a) {

    int x[ countLinesOf() ];

    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("ClientList.txt");
    string str;
    for (int i = 0; i< countLinesOf();i++){
        while (getline(readFile, str)) {
            reverseStr2(str);
            str.erase(3);
            reverseStr2(str);
            stringstream geek(str);
            geek >> x[i];
            if( x[i]==a ){
                cout<<a<<" is equal to "<<x[i]<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    readFile.close();
}
```

Comment: You generally can't modify a text file in-place. You have to use some temporary storage (like another file, or an in-memory buffer).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I came across that on a lot of other discussions but I was thinking perhaps a way with manipulating file pointers perhaps to show me the location(binary most probably) of where such value would be in the file.

Comment: The problem is, what if the new "value" is less or more characters than the current "value"? Then you will either overwrite too few too many characters in the file. The only this can work if the new test you write is ***exactly*** the same size as the old.

Comment: For file pointer manipulation you can use fstream functions seekp, seekg, tellg, tellp. And you should use fstream (imho) instead of ifstream.

Comment: And you shouldn't use pointer arithmetics (current pointer plus size of line, etc): for text files it can cause errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they are actually the same size. The function above makes sure that the into each one of the array's positions is stored a three digit number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the same file it's slightly difficult.

For example you can open the same file twice: for reading strings and for saving strings.
Your cycle would be: read string, save string (if it doesn't contain suitable number).

Another trouble is to cut file to lower size. You can use boost::filesystem or native api.

Comment: I understand your logic yet what function should I use to assign the file pointer at the beginning of the line where said string would be found.

Comment: you should get file pointer by calling teelg. You should call that member before you call getline.